# iCloud Setup Fails: Failed to migrate baseline, unable to create ubiquity migration manager

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7, icloud

I'm new to iCloud, and I've gotten it to work in the past, but I started getting this error:

```
-[PFUbiquitySwitchboardEntryMetadata setUseLocalStorage:](771): 
CoreData: Ubiquity:  clifton~sim70A83865-2E36-5810-ABEE-88CBF9EED011:iCloudPilotPro
Using local storage: 1
```

It is soon followed by this error:

```
-[PFUbiquitySetupAssistant finishSetupWithRetry:](822): 
CoreData: Ubiquity:  <PFUbiquitySetupAssistant: 0x1095bc790>: Retrying after delay: 60
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134060 "The operation couldn’t be completed. 
(Cocoa error 134060.)" UserInfo=0x1095c3740 {reason=Failed to migrate baseline, unable 
to create ubiquity migration manager}
```

I've scoured the web for any mention of `unable to create ubiquity migration manager` and I haven't found anything. Core Data seems to run fine in my app, but iCloud won't sync.

Does anyone out there know what this means or have ideas of what I can try?